# What is a simple way to prove that the point-wise limit of the sequence $\{kx^k\}_{k\in \Bbb N}$ is $0$.

Tags: real-analysis

What is a simple way to prove that the point-wise limit of the sequence $\{kx^k\}_{k\in \Bbb N}$ is $0$.

I have proved it using L'hospitals rule, however I want to know if there is a more basic way of proving the result.

Comment: You are using $x\in (-1,1)$. Am I right?